# Procedure invocation failed: ContextPath/authorization/v1/testtoken

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm using mobilefirst 7.1 for eclipse juno on windows 7.

I tried to call default adapter which is created by mobilefirst it is showing an error

Procedure invocation failed: ContextPath/authorization/v1/testtoken

what might be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 does not support Eclipse Juno. First use either Eclipse Kepler or Mars, install the latest available 7.1 build from the Eclipse Marketplace and see if it is failing still.

If it will continue to fail, provide full reproduction steps.